# Timing problem between OnInit and async-pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

I have a problem with the `async`-pipe in combination with an `Observable` which gets it's first value in `OnInit`. Must be a timing issue about the point in time when `OnInit` happens and the one when the template gets rendered and thus the `Observable` get subscribed.

Consider this component:

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    subjectA$: Subject<{name:string}>;
    subjectB$: Subject<{name:string}>;

    constructor(
        protected http: HttpClient
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subjectA$ = new Subject<{name: string}>();
        this.subjectA$.next({name: "A"});

        this.subjectB$ = new Subject<{name: string}>();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.subjectB$.next({name: "B"});
        }, 0);
    }

}
```

and the template:

```html
<p *ngIf='subjectA$ | async as subjectA; else: nosubjectA'>
  subjectA: {{subjectA.name}}
</p>

<ng-template #nosubjectA>
  <p>no subjectA</p>
</ng-template>

<p *ngIf='subjectB$ | async as subjectB; else: nosubjectB'>
  subjectB: {{subjectB.name}}
</p>

<ng-template #nosubjectB>
  <p>no subjectB</p>
</ng-template>
```

This results in

```
no subjectA

subjectB: B
```

That means: Even if `subjectA$` got a value in `onInit`, the view is not updated. If I wrap around the creation of the first value in a `setTimeout` as you can see with `subjectB$`, it works and I see the value. Although this is a solution I am wondering **why does this this happen and is there a better solution?**

One solution I already found would be using `BehaviorSubject` instead an provide the first value as initial value:

```ts
        this.subjectC$ = new BehaviorSubject<{name: string}>({name: "C"});
```

leads to `subjectC: C` with analogous template for subjectC.

[Try all on StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nginit-async-problem)

My real observable is no `Subject` at all but the result of a `combineLatest`-call of different stuff, from which only one is (and have to unfortunately since it is using a value from an `@Input()`-annotation) a `Subject`, and manually pushed with `next` in `OnInit` as in the example. The rest comes from `http` et al. Most likely I could wrap the combined result in a `BehaviourSubject` but it seems ugly and dangerous to me, so it's even worse then the `setTimeout` approach. But I bet someone can help me out and find a real useful solution.
In addition, I would prefer to avoid `BehaviorSubject`, to prevent developers from being tempted to use `getValue`.

[See on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nginit-async-problem-7wnvts)

Comment: had a similar problem recently (specifically converting the @Input into an observable) and i was able to solve by using `shareReplay(1)` (or use a `ReplaySubject` with a buffer of 1) for the observable - the problem with doing .next inside `ngOnInit` seems like it runs first before the template actually subscribes to the observables. Moving things to ngAfterViewInit (or ngAfterContentInit) doesn't really solve the problem too as change detection will complain. So all I was left with is to replay the last value, store it in a `BehaviorSubject`, or use `setTimeout` as well.

Comment: Okay that means I don't should be too optimistic for trying out other hooks than `onInit`... How can the internet be full of advices to use `async` instead of manual subscription but don't have a suitable solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comment I made, I really couldn't help but think that there must be a better way - and finally thought of something that worked!

I just modified your stackblitz a bit.

```
private valueA = "A";
private valueB = "B";

subjectA$ = of({ name: this.valueA });
subjectB$ = of({ name: this.valueB });
subjectC$ = combineLatest([this.subjectA$, this.subjectB$])
          .pipe(
            map((things: [{name:string}, {name:string}]): {name:string} => {return {name: things.map(x => x.name).join('|')}})
          );
```

This way, we can even discard the `ngOnInit` hook, and everything works at it should!

Comment: At a first glance this seemed to be the perfect solution, clean, simple and not feeling like a workaround. And for many similar cases it might be it. But as I wrote, I need a value from an `@Input()`-annotation, to calculate the (first) content of one of the combines Observables - which is not present at construction time, but in `onInit`. I thought, the solution would be to initialize the Observables at construction time, and give them their first value in `onInit` - but no, you would still need the `setTimeout`-hack. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nginit-async-problem-3

Comment: Apologies... but I really think I've got it this time. Since right now, `of` creates a hot observable and since the value of the input is really not available initially, the value would not have been available. So I think what we really need is a cold observable.

I updated your stackblitz to really show what you need - with a separate component and the 2 `@Inputs` a and b. https://stackblitz.com/edit/nginit-async-problem-3-y6qxuo

Comment: I am stunned that this works, and when `@Input` actually get populated, but nevertheless I think this is a suitable solution.

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix would be to use [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with buffer 1 instead of `BehaviorSubject`. You do not have to provide a default value and it neither has the `getValue()` function nor `value` getter. And yet it buffers (or holds) the last emitted value and emits it immediately upon new subscriptions.

Try the following

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.subjectA$ = new ReplaySubject<{name: string}>(1);
  this.subjectA$.next({name: "A"});

  this.subjectB$ = new ReplaySubject<{name: string}>(1);
  this.subjectB$.next({name: "B"});

  this.subjectC$ = combineLatest([this.subjectA$, this.subjectB$]).pipe(
    map((things: [{name:string}, {name:string}]): {name:string} => {
      return {name: things.map(thing => thing.name).join('|')}
    })
  );
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nginit-async-problem-w6iuvn).

Comment: Thank you, without question a better approach then `BehaviorSubject`. But still still feels more like a workaround than a solution. The underlying problem comes clearly from the order of `ngInit` and subscription of `async`, and the way angular handles the next call when made asynchronous (but still immediately since `setTimeout` is called with `0`). I guess I one understood these things well, one could come up with a solution directly approaching to than (and use another hook for example or whatever).

Comment: @Paflow: If you wish to understand why it works if you call the `setTimeout` with `0`, you could see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/6513921).